# How to compare user & group recursively in two different folders?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have two folders both with many subfolders and files in it. For example:

```
/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/ 
/wordpress/htdocs2/wp-content/
```

Below these two folders there is each a complete struture of many subfolders and files. What I would like to do is to compare ownership (in a second command permissions) of each file that exists in both substructures. Where ever there are differences I would like to have them displayed.

The result should look something like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 group1 104343 Oct 23  2017 /wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/images/comment.jpg     ||    -rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 group2 104343 May 15  2018 /wordpress/htdocs2/wp-content/images/comment.jpg
```

After executing the command that I am searching for here, these two lines would be displayed because the group is different for the "same" file (same file but in differnt folders).

```
user1 group1   ||   user1 group2
```

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

What I have tried is to use the command below in both folders and compare the output files. However this does not work as modification times are differnt for almost all files. So it does not narrow it down to the really relevant information.

```
sudo find . -exec ls -l -all {} \; | sudo tee usergroup.txt >/dev/null
```

And then I used this command to compare the results:

```
diff -c /wordpress/htdocs/usergroup.txt /wordpress/htdocs2/usergroup.txt
```

But as said the result was too large and not really helpfull.

1. How can I solve this - best with a one liner?
2. Just for curiosity: How can I make `diff` to display (or output into a file) the **entire** line when using syde-by-side? It normaly cuts the line at a certain length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ls -l` output includes the modification time of each file, which is very likely to be different between the two file trees, which is why `diff` reports them.

You should use `find`'s `-printf '…'` option and only print the relevant information. This would also spare a lot of `ls` processes. Do that twice on both trees and the output can be compared more sanely.

(By the way, `find` reports files AND folders, and your `… -exec ls -al {} \;` on a folder will display its content AGAIN -- and other noise like `.` and `..`. You could suppress that with `-d`, but as I already said, you should avoid using `ls` altogether, because its primary purpose is to *list* (hence, the name) the contents of a directory, and not to `stat` single files).

When using `diff` in side-by-side mode (`-y`) it has to cut off every line at *some* point, because you asked it to display the second stream nice and neatly *right next* to the first one. The default is to output at most 130 characters per line (I guess), but you may change that with `-W`. Personally, I would avoid the side-by-side display altogether, but here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash

diff -y -W 300 --suppress-common-lines \
    <(find /path1/wp-content -printf '%u %g %m %P\n') \
    <(find /path2/wp-content -printf '%u %g %m %P\n')
```

Have a look at `man diff` and `man find` (the part about `-printf`) for what things you can print about a file like its size. In order to suppress folders from the `find` output, you should put a `-type f` before the `-printf` part (i.e. only find real files before printing). My example may not fully answer your question, but you get the idea.

PS: `diff` will usually output some *context* lines near differing lines in order for humans and machines to more easily find those lines in the original files. In fact, in side-by-side mode, `diff` will actually always display *everything* by default -- no matter if there are differences or not. The option to `--suppress-common-lines` will suppress that. In normal mode (not side-by-side) that option will also somewhat change the output format of `diff` -- including `<` and `>` in front of each differing line. Maybe that should be enough and easily readable, so you don't need the side-by-side option altogether. Just give it a try.

Comment: Excellent answer I'd say. Thank you very much! I have tested it and it shows me exactly what I wanted to know. And I've learned somthing.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, a very contrived way of solving this problem:

```
find /wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/ a/wordpress/htdocs2/wp-content/ \
     -type f -exec stat {} --printf '%n %A\n' \; | \
     sed 's!.*/wp-content/!!' | sort | uniq -u | sed 'N;s/\n/ || /'
```